# plupload - uploader.start() results in javascript error when queue is empty

Tags: javascript, file-upload, plupload

Calling `uploader.start()` before any files are selected results in error in plupload. For example, if you look at the `example/custom.html` which goes in plupload 1.5.2 and first click on the `"Upload files"` button, you get a javascript error:

> q is undefined

If you look at the [example at the website](http://plupload.com/example_custom.php), it works, because the script "/plupload/js/plupload.full.js" which is used on the website is different version than the last released (1.5.2). But if you use the 1.5.2 latest release version the above problem appears.

**Are there any workarounds for plupload 1.5.2?**

Edit: the issue [is reported](https://github.com/moxiecode/plupload/issues/505).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround:

```
if (uploader.files.length > 0)
    uploader.start()
```